# How to read from .env file in electron-builder yaml config file?

Tags: javascript, electron, environment-variables, electron-builder

I am new to electron. I have an angular application wrapped in electron that I want to build the package/installer using `electron-builder`. I am using `electron-builder-config.yaml` file to build the installer.

I would like to know how do I read values from `.env` environment file into `electron-builder-config.yaml` file ?

I want to set the version of the package that is generated by command `electron-builder -w --publish always -c ./builder-config.yaml`.

I did try using `buildVersion` property but the problem is that there is an `installer.nsh` file that needs to run as part of nsis installer to set the path and that file uses `${version}`.

There is very little [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html#environment-variables-from-file) on environment variables usage in electron-builder-config.yaml

Here is my `electron-builder-config.yaml`

```
directories:
  output: ./dist/electron
  buildResources: ./electron/build
  app: ''
electronVersion: X.Y.Z
appId:  com.sample.app
copyright: "Copyright © 2020 ${author}"
productName: TestApp
forceCodeSigning: true
artifactName: "${productName}-${os}-${version}.${ext}"
files:
  - "**/dist/electron/*"
  - "**/electron/*"
asar: true
compression: maximum
mac:
  category: public.app-category.reference
  icon: "./icon-file.icns"
  publish: [{
      "provider": "generic",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080"
  }]
dmg:
  background: "./build/sample.jpg"
  icon: "./build/nw.icns"
  iconSize: 96
  contents:
    - x: 650
      y: 230
      type: link
      path: /Applications
    - x: 350
      y: 230
      type: file
win:
  cscLink: "./somelink.pfx"
  cscKeyPassword: "XXXXXX"
  target: [nsis]
  icon: "./appinfo.ico"
  publish: [{
      "provider": "generic",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080"
  }]
msi:
  shortcutName: "TestApp - ${version}"
  createDesktopShortcut: true
  createStartMenuShortcut: true
nsis:
  include: "./installer.nsh"
  installerIcon: "./appinfo.ico"
  uninstallerIcon: "./appinfo.ico"
  packElevateHelper: true
  allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true
  perMachine: true
  oneClick: false
  createDesktopShortcut: true
  createStartMenuShortcut: true
  shortcutName: "TestApp - ${version}"
  guid: "someguid"
npmRebuild: true
nodeGypRebuild: false
```

Also, I am not sure about the macro `${ext}`. From where does this `electron-builder-config.yaml` file is picking up this value ? Even in the [documentation for file-macros](https://www.electron.build/file-patterns#file-macros), the version does not have the clear definition.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it figured out. In case someone else is looking for the answer to this question, here is how I got it working.

**Step 1:** Create a file by the name `electron-builder.env` at the root level where your `package.json` resides. Please make sure that you keep the file name as **`electron-builder.env`**

**Step 2:** Define the variables that you would like to inside the `electron-builder.env` file, for example *ELECTRON_BUILD_VERSION=99.99*

**Step 3:** Inside your `builder-config.yaml` file, access the environment variable with the syntax **`{env.ELECTRON_BUILD_VERSION}`**

There you go. Have fun. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to read env file directly, use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package:

```
npm i dotenv
```

```js
// Inside the main process file
require('dotenv').config();
const GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY = process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY
```

Comment: Tried this, it's not working.

Comment: @Dastan
I use typescript environment, please put the .env file on the project root then check this out:
`require('dotenv').config({ path: require('path').join(__dirname, '.env') });`

Comment: Also for "build" you have to copy the .env file into main process path with a webpack plugin